# Why is Outlook's exported datafile so large

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup

As I'm quitting my job next week, I have to export my emails for my successors. One thing that I found very strange is that the size of the exported Outlook data is way too large. With a duration of 1 year and a half, average 5 emails per day, and absolutely no attached documents, no calendar appointments , and yet the exported data's size is approximately 550MB. That's unacceptable in my opinion. So my question is, why is the file so large because as I see, my data is purely `text`.

Comment: Barring strange bugs, exports are exactly as large as the data they contain. Are you underestimating the size most emails are these days? Signatures, images, screenshots, attachments, mails sent to expanded distribution lists, ... It all adds up. Have you checked the folder size of your mailbox? Have you checked for large attachments?

Comment: Just check your current mailbox size and compare with your exported file first.

Answer (score 1):

That is a more or less normal size for an Outlook PST file. Outlook PST files with attachments are much larger.

An Outlook PST file is a proprietary database and that is one thing that contributes to its size.

Based on a lot of experience over a lot of years with Outlook, I would suggest that is a normal size for 18 or so months work.

You can if you wish (from within Outlook) run the Compact function to reduce the size. In this case, you would need to compact and export again or load the resulting file into Outlook as another file and then compact it that way. There is no formula for how much it reduces.

Comment: Outlook also has a feature to compact (optimize) the .PST file.  This should significantly reduce the size (but mileage will vary)